# Using denyAll() and permitAll() together Spring security 3.0.8 not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We got a Web Application which is secured using Spring security 3.0.8. We use DWR for ajax, quite a lot. Now we want to deny access to all DWR calls unless specified explicitly:

This is what I did, but doesn't work:

```
<!-- Deny every url which is dwr call -->
<intercept-url pattern="/js/dwr/**/**DWR**" access="denyAll"/>

<!-- give access to SomeDWRClass for ROLE_A -->
<intercept-url pattern="/js/dwr/**/SomeDWRClass**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_A')"/>

<!-- Give access to everybody for CommonDwr.aCommonMethod.dwr -->
<intercept-url pattern="/js/dwr/CommonDwr.aCommonMethod.dwr" access="permitAll"/>
```

The problem is whenever there is a call to **CommonDwr.aCommonMethod.dwr** its showing **access denied.** Why? Is it because **denyAll** has got more precedence over **permitAll?**.

If so or not, how do I solve this issue? I am sure there are lot of people out there who have had to secure their application like this.

The main reason why we are doing this is if some new person comes and write a new DWR class, by default the permission should be denied, so that they can explicitly set an access role for the new class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `intercept-url` patterns are matched in the order listed.
As soon as a match is found, the rest of the patterns specified are ignored.

This is why you should list more specific patterns earlier.

In your case the specific url patterns comes later. So the `denyAll` found first and picked that one.

Reverese the order like

```
<!-- Give access to everybody for CommonDwr.aCommonMethod.dwr -->
<intercept-url pattern="/js/dwr/CommonDwr.aCommonMethod.dwr" access="permitAll"/>

<!-- give access to SomeDWRClass for ROLE_A -->
<intercept-url pattern="/js/dwr/**/SomeDWRClass**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_A')"/>

<!-- Deny every url which is dwr call -->
<intercept-url pattern="/js/dwr/**/**DWR**" access="denyAll"/>
```

See [Core Security Filters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html)

However I dont understand the reason

> The main reason why we are doing this is if some new person comes and write a new DWR class, by default the permission should be denied, so that they can explicitly set an access role for the new class

Creating roles to restrict developers ? Usually Roles are meant to the users and functionality that app provides.

Comment: Thanks. "Creating roles to restrict developers" - No not actually. We are just following the security policy - "default deny"